# Can't add plugins using `phonegap plugin add XXX`

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

I've installed phonegap version 3 using `npm install -g phonegap` and now i want to install plugins for the andriod app

I installed node.js

```
C:\var\www\sexdiaries.co.uk\app>node -v 
v0.10.17
```

Then Phonegapy

```
phonegap plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git
```

But this gives this error:

```
   [error] 'plugin' is not a node C:\Users\Hutber\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\bin\phonegap.js command. 
   See 'node C:\Users\Hutber\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\bin\phonegap.js help'
```

Comment: haha, just had the same problem and found this answer :p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git
```

Comment: to install npm I had to install node.js :(

Comment: ha, needed it again :)